# Poblar RecyclerView con MySql

Tags: php, mysql, android, volley

**Buenas, esstoy tratando de poblar un `RecyclerView` con datos de mi `BD` en **MySql** pero no me estaría saliendo ya que cuando inicio la actividad no me figura nada en el `RecyclerView`. Este es mi archivo php:

```
<?php
    $servername = 'asd';
    $database = 'asd';
    $username = 'asd';
    $password = 'ads';
    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
          die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    
    $sql = "SELECT z.nombreZona, cpp.precioMinimo, cpp.precioMaximo, cpp.promedio FROM cargaPrecioPapas cpp INNER JOIN zonas z ON cpp.fkZona = z.idZona";
    
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows >0) {
       while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           $tem = $row;
           $json = json_encode($tem);
        }
    } else {
 echo "No Results Found.";
}
 echo $json;
 $conn->close();
```

Es funcional:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi adaptador:

```
public class AdaptadorListaPrecios extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorListaPrecios.ViewHolderPrecios> {
    ArrayList<ListaPrecios> listaPreciosArrayList;
    private Context context;

    public AdaptadorListaPrecios(Context context, ArrayList<ListaPrecios> listaPreciosArrayList1){
        this.context = context;
        this.listaPreciosArrayList = listaPreciosArrayList1;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolderPrecios onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int position){
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model, null, false);
        return  new ViewHolderPrecios(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderPrecios viewHolderPrecios, int position){
        viewHolderPrecios.zona.setText(listaPreciosArrayList.get(position).getZona());
        viewHolderPrecios.premin.setText(listaPreciosArrayList.get(position).getPremin());
        viewHolderPrecios.premax.setText(listaPreciosArrayList.get(position).getPremax());
        viewHolderPrecios.prom.setText(listaPreciosArrayList.get(position).getProm());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return listaPreciosArrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolderPrecios extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView zona, premin, premax, prom;

        public ViewHolderPrecios(@NonNull View view){
            super(view);

            zona = view.findViewById(R.id.tvCiudad);
            premin = view.findViewById(R.id.tvMin);
            premax = view.findViewById(R.id.tvMax);
            prom = view.findViewById(R.id.tvProm);
        }
    }
}
```

Mi clase:

```
public class ListaPrecios {
    private String zona;
    private String premin;
    private String premax;
    private String prom;

    public String getZona() {
        return zona;
    }

    public void setZona(String zona) {
        this.zona = zona;
    }

    public String getPremin() {
        return premin;
    }

    public void setPremin(String premin) {
        this.premin = premin;
    }

    public String getPremax() {
        return premax;
    }

    public void setPremax(String premax) {
        this.premax = premax;
    }

    public String getProm() {
        return prom;
    }

    public void setProm(String prom) {
        this.prom = prom;
    }

    public ListaPrecios(String zona, String premin, String premax, String prom) {
        this.zona = zona;
        this.premin = premin;
        this.premax = premax;
        this.prom = prom;
    }

    public ListaPrecios() { }
}
```

Y esta es mi actividad:

```
public class ListaPreciosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerListaPrecios;
    Button carga,cerrar;
    ArrayList<ListaPrecios> listaPreciosArrayList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_precios);

        listaPreciosArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerListaPrecios = findViewById(R.id.RecyclerListaPrecios);
        recyclerListaPrecios.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ListaPreciosActivity.this));
        recyclerListaPrecios.setHasFixedSize(true);
        listaPreciosPapa();
    }

    public void listaPreciosPapa() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://flmprogamma.com/listaprecios.php",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("$tem");

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String zona = jsonObject1.getString("nombreZona");
                                String premin = jsonObject1.getString("precioMinimo");
                                String premax = jsonObject1.getString("precioMaximo");
                                String prom = jsonObject1.getString("promedio");
                                listaPreciosArrayList.add(new ListaPrecios(zona,premin,premax,prom));
                            }
                            AdaptadorListaPrecios adaptador = new AdaptadorListaPrecios(getApplicationContext(), listaPreciosArrayList);
                            recyclerListaPrecios.setAdapter(adaptador);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ListaPreciosActivity.this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void cargarPrecio(){
        Intent precios = new Intent(ListaPreciosActivity.this, CargaPrecios.class);
        startActivity(precios);
    }

    private void cerrarSesion(){
        Intent cerrar = new Intent(ListaPreciosActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(cerrar);
    }
}
```

Y así es como se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien me dice donde está mi error? Gracias

Comment: Revisa la traza de la pila, debes tener un error ahí. En tu captura de la respuesta lo que se ve es un `JSONArray`, (eso lo delimitan los símbolos `[` y `]`), por tanto, esto no es correcto: `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response); JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("$tem");`, no sé de donde sacas ese `$tem`¿? Como dije, tu respuesta es un array, entonces, así debería funcionar: `JSONArray jsonArray =new JSONArray(response);` **se sobre-entiende que debes borrar las dos líneas anteriores**. Prueba así y haz debug de tu código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu captura de la respuesta lo que se ve es un `JSONArray`, (eso lo delimitan los símbolos `[` y `]`), por tanto, esto no es correcto:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response); 
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("$tem");
```

¿Por qué buscas en `response` un `JSONObject`, cuando es un `JSONArray`?

¿Por qué buscas un `JSONArray` en una supuesta propiedad `$tem` que no existe? Además, dudo que el estándar JSON permita poner nombres de propiedades empezando por `$`.

Prueba de este modo:

```
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            //resto del código
                        }
```

Así debería funcionar, si no hay otros errores adicionales en tu código. Te recomiendo que revises la traza de la pila en caso de estar usando `printStackTrace()`o que depures las etapas del código con `Log.d()`. Sin duda que tendrás en la pila la información actual de los errores de tu código, al querer crear un JSONObject que no existe en `response`.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, era eso